# English Translation of Zohar online

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, translation, english, zohar

I'm looking something up in the *Zohar* on Bereishis (Genesis), but I can't translate the words. Does anyone know where I can find an English translation of the *Zohar* on Bereishis, that's online?

Comment: I'm not saying that **any** of these are reliable, but why don't you try a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=english+zohar+online&oq=english+zohar+online&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.3052j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl)?

Comment: Maybe use some Aramaic/gemoro dictionary to translate the words

Comment: Do you know of website that has a Aramaic/gemoro dictionary online?

Comment: The Jastrow dictionary is available here: http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/

Comment: You can also use the Comprehensive Aramaic Lexicon if you want a more interactive Aramaic dictionary. (In other words, you can type in a word and search instead of having to flip through jpeg images to find the one which contains your word). http://cal.huc.edu/

Comment: Also try [this one](http://ha-zohar.net/ZOHAR_ENGLISH.htm) from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zohar#English_translations)

Comment: @paquda - The Aramaic of the Zohar is much different than the Aramaic of the Gemara and other Rabbinic literature. I doubt you would get very far trying to translate the Zohar with a dictionary like Jastrow's.

Comment: @ezra, it's worked well for me. I don't recall ever looking up a word I encountered in a zohar passage, and not finding it.

Comment: Nice, well I guess I was wrong then. I assumed Jastrow's Talmudic dictionary wouldn't work with Zoharic Aramaic... Just goes to show never assume.

Answer (score 6):

Chabad has a [partial translation online](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1384833/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Book-of-Genesis.htm). it includes the parts that are included in hok l'yisrael. The translation is by Rabbi Rahmiel-Hayyim Drizin. I don't know if that will include what you're looking for. There's also a partial translation from 1904 [online at sacred-texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/zdm/index.htm). The Kabbalah Education and Research center [has one](http://www.kabbalah.info/engkab/the-zohar/download-the-zohar#.VBCecvldW6M), but I'm not sure if it's complete either. The [Pritzker Edition by Daniel Matt](http://www.sup.org/zohar/) is the first critical edition in English to be made, and will be complete once it's done, however it's in hard copy and is still in progress - as of right now 8 of 12 total volumes have been published (Although Bereshit is clearly finished by now).

Comment: "and will be complete once it's done" :) +1

Comment: @DoubleAA lol. I guess that does look kinda funny when you read it. :-) What I was trying to say was that the Matt edition is aiming to be a complete translation, unlike some of the prior ones that limited their scope to only certain sections of the Zohar.

Answer (score 1):

I use this site a lot for all my Zohar question. Chanoch is very easy to talk with and if you have qquestions send him an email.

http://www.yeshshem.com//zohar-links-parasha-beraishit.htm

Answer (score -2):

Chiddushei Torah, have you visited: [www.Zohar.com](http://www.zohar.com/) for the English translation of Beresheet?

Note however that you have to sign up to see most of the content.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Does that link have a translation of the Zohar *on* B'reishit, or B'reishit itself? From your comment it sounds like the latter, but the asker is asking for the former.

Comment: Many people on this site would not visit zohar.com because of its association with the Kabbalah Center.

Answer (score -3):

Zohar with English on the whole Torah - 50 parashiyot.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwRFZRSGYc-3X0xhUXlqb05MdXc

This is the same translation available below at zohar.com, translated and hosted by the Kabbalah Center, with the addition of a prologue.

Comment: This is the Kaballah Center's translation. See here to compare the two https://www.zohar.com/zohar. Not considered kosher by most.

Comment: I'd be very, very worried about recommending anything of Michael Berg or the Kabbalah Centre, particularly on such a sensitive topic as Kabbalah and the Zohar. [They are literally a cult.](https://youtu.be/kiSYkERzFVA)