# Where can I find the Zohar in french or english?

Tags: product-recommendation, zohar

Where can I find it in french it english? It may be a paper or e-book, or a blog, I don't really care. I am just looking for an accurate translation (besides the Sonccino one that I already know).

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45128/759

Comment: Not quite a dupe, @DoubleAA. That one wants English online. This one is broader: English or French; physical or digital. An answer to the other would be an acceptable answer to this too, though.

Comment: like the sulam edition or just a literal translation? http://www.kabbalah.info/engkab/the-zohar/download-the-zohar#.VMa6Co10yVM

Comment: I do not really care. I need a translation to help me understand the original version in Hebrew.

Comment: @far22  <<I need a translation to help me understand the original version in Hebrew>> The original Zohar is not written in Hebrew. Most of it is in Aramaic.

Comment: @far22 alternatively, learn Hebrew to read the numerous Hebrew translations of the Aramaic

Answer (score 1):

Prof. Daniel Matt has a 12-volume translation and commentary of the Zohar in English, see [here](https://www.sup.org/zohar/) or [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_2_6?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=zohar%20pritzker%20edition&sprefix=zohar%20%2Caps%2C310&crid=35ZIWBVVBI3BS). The publisher's summary reads

> This is the first translation ever made from a critical Aramaic text
>   of the Zohar, which has been established by Professor Daniel Matt
>   based on a wide range of original manuscripts. The work spans twelve
>   volumes. The extensive commentary, appearing at the bottom of each
>   page, clarifies the kabbalistic symbolism and terminology, and cites
>   sources and parallels from biblical, rabbinic, and kabbalistic texts.

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_HaZohar#Traductions_en_fran%C3%A7ais) lists some French translations but I never saw them.

Comment: have you ever used this one? You described it to be pretty good for an english reader.

Comment: I have not. My experience is that, even when you have the text, you need an experienced rav to understand it. Otherwise you miss most of the meaning. Check it out yourself in translation, starting from the links [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45128/english-translation-of-zohar-online?rq=1)

Comment: thank you. Very helpful. Good Mo'ed!